# Transparent Glass is not transparent in material preview

Tags: glass

I'm new to Blender and this as for sure asked before, but I couldn't find someone how had the exact same problem as me. This is my material:

[image]

This is how it looks when I set the viewport to rendered (with Cycles):

[image]

And this is how it look when I set the viewport to material preview:

[image]

My question is, if it is possible to get the glass transparent in the material preview as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Material Preview* is identical to Eevee, so you need to tweak some parameters in Eevee in order to see glass transparency, like enable the *Screen Space Refraction* option of the material and in the Eevee render panel enable *Screen Space Reflections* and the *Refraction* option.

Comment: +1 but maybe as additional clarification for beginners, when using _Cycles_ as _Render Engine_ like in the question, the _Screen Space Refraction_ of the material is found under _Viewport Display_ (and it helps for accuracy to set a correct _Refraction Depth_ value). However, to set the _Screen Space Reflections_ and _Refraction_ in the _Render Properties_ you **have to switch to _Eevee_** (I'm not sure if this gets clear enough from the answer) to change these settings. And if you did not change the material before switching, those options are now under _Settings_, not _Viewport Display_.

Comment: Oh ok thanks forthe additional info